# invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios6

I have updated a very old project of mine(XCODE 4.5.1 baseSDK iOS6) and for some reason i get the error above.

it compiles only for iOS5+
but not with iOS 4.3

?

any idea ?

Comment: Does the problem resolved? I meet the same problem

Comment: No, i left it that way and released it to iOS 5+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the C++ Standard Library to libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard) in the target Build Settings, as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html).

Comment: the link has been broken :(